# EditText textmultiline to display 3 lines by default

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-linearlayout

Android Studio 0.4.4

Hello,

I would like the EditText property textmultiline to display 3 lines by default. However, I can't seen to do that. As it always displays 1 line. Is there any way I can do this using the LinearLayout?

Here is my xml file:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvName"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="22sp"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvPhone"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="22sp"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvEmail"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="22sp"/>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etMessage"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="22sp"
    android:hint="Enter your message"
    android:inputType="textImeMultiLine"
    android:minLines="3"
    android:gravity="top|left">

    <requestFocus/>
</EditText>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnSendMessage"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Send Message"
    android:textSize="22sp"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivEmailPicture"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:contentDescription="Picture of email being send"
    android:src="@drawable/email"/>
```

And a screen shot of my current design, as you can see the editText (Enter your message) is only displaying 1 line.

Many thanks for any suggestions,

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this to your EditText's xml code.

```
android:lines="3"
```

I'm not sure if it will solve your problem but refering to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3alines) it should.

Comment: I removed the minlines and replaced with with your suggestion. However, that didn't work. Actually, I have tried all this before. I am not sure if he has something to do with the gravity of the surrounding controls.

Comment: May not be a very elegant solution but can't you put a simple string with 3 linebreaks ( "\n\n\n" ) as a text? Respectively can you see all 3 lines if you put text in it? If not the other views may be occupying the needed place..

Comment: Its working now. What I did was delete the control and then added a new one to the xml. This solved my problem. Thanks.

Comment: it won't work if you have `android:inputType="text"`

Answer (score 4):

You need to change the "android:lines" value of the EditText:
Your code should look like this:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvName"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="22sp"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvPhone"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="22sp"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvEmail"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="22sp"/>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etMessage"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="22sp"
    android:hint="Enter your message"
    android:inputType="textImeMultiLine"
    android:lines="3"
    android:minLines="3"
    android:gravity="top|left">

    <requestFocus/>
</EditText>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnSendMessage"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Send Message"
    android:textSize="22sp"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivEmailPicture"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:contentDescription="Picture of email being send"
    android:src="@drawable/email"/>

    <requestFocus/>
</EditText>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnSendMessage"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Send Message"
    android:textSize="22sp"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivEmailPicture"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:contentDescription="Picture of email being send"
    android:src="@drawable/email"/>
```

Good luck! :)

Comment: @Swedish. I have tried setting the lines and minlines. I couldn't getting it to work. I have been messing around with this for about a hour now. Not sure what the problem is. I thought it might be something simple. I am thinking something to do with layout_gravity. Thanks.

Comment: @Swedish, Its working now. What I did was delete the control and then added a new one to the xml. This solved my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

android:lines="3"
android:ellipsize="end"

ellipsize "end" for mode loadingMore...

Comment: mehrdad ghadermarzi, while this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30940662)